# Make a bottom right fixed element rise above footer

Tags: css, css-position

I was wondering how I could make a div that I have fixed to the bottom right of my screen become unfixed once the page reaches the footer.

For example if my html is:

```
<div class="main" />
<div class="fixed" />
<div class="footer" />
```

And my css is:

```
.main {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: aqua;
    width: 100vw;
}

.fixed {
    background-color: green;
    height: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 200px;
}

.footer {
    background-color: brown;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

I would like to have my fixed div in the bottom until the footer starts to be revealed and then have it scroll on top of the footer. Should I use sticky positioning? If so how do I do that? If not is there a better solution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `position: sticky` along with `bottom: 0` to stick it to the bottom of the viewport (to answer your question of *how*). Since it's non-sticky location is right before the footer, it will rest naturally when the viewport reaches there.

```css
body {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-bottom: 300px;
}

main * {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.content {
  min-height: 1000px;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  /* the important part - stick to the bottom */
  bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="content">content</div>
  <div class="sticky">I'm sticky</div>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</main>
```

That being said, as mentioned in the comment by Will - *should you use it*? That depends on what browsers you support. If you need to support older browsers, you'll need a fallback and/or JavaScript to handle the positioning.

Comment: Browser support here: https://caniuse.com/?search=sticky. IE doesn't support it. It's a good solution if you're comfortable with its level of support.